# AWS VPC - Internet Gateway vs. NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

What is an Internet Gateway? What is a NAT Instance? What services do they offer?

Reading AWS VPC documentation, I gather they both map private IP addresses to internet route-able addresses for the outgoing requests and route the incoming responses from the internet to the requester on the subnet.

So what are the differences between them? What scenarios do I use a NAT Instance instead of (or besides) an Internet Gateway? 
Are they essentially EC2 instances running some network applications or are they special hardware like a router?

Instead of simply pointing to AWS documentation links, can you please explain these with adding some background on what is public and private subnets so any beginner with limited knowledge of networking can understand these easily?
Also when should I use a NAT Gateway instead of a NAT instance?

P.S. I am new to AWS VPC, so I might be comparing apples to oranges here.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

**Internet Gateway**

An Internet Gateway is a **logical connection between an Amazon VPC and the Internet**. It is *not* a physical device. Only one can be associated with each VPC. It does *not* limit the bandwidth of Internet connectivity. (The only limitation on bandwidth is the size of the Amazon EC2 instance, and it applies to all traffic -- internal to the VPC and out to the Internet.)

If a VPC **does not** have an Internet Gateway, then the resources in the VPC **cannot be accessed from the Internet** (unless the traffic flows via a corporate network and VPN/Direct Connect).

A subnet is deemed to be a **Public Subnet** if it has a Route Table that directs traffic to the Internet Gateway.

**NAT Instance**

A NAT Instance is an Amazon EC2 instance configured to forward traffic to the Internet. It can be launched from an existing AMI, or can be configured via User Data like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/send_redirects
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
mkdir -p /etc/sysctl.d/
cat <<EOF > /etc/sysctl.d/nat.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0
EOF
```

Instances in a private subnet that want to access the Internet can have their Internet-bound traffic forwarded to the NAT Instance via a Route Table configuration. The NAT Instance will then make the request to the Internet (since it is in a Public Subnet) and the response will be forwarded back to the private instance.

Traffic sent to a NAT Instance will typically be sent to an IP address that is not associated with the NAT Instance itself (it will be destined for a server on the Internet). Therefore, it is important to turn off the **Source/Destination Check** option on the NAT Instance otherwise the traffic will be blocked.

**NAT Gateway**

AWS introduced a **NAT Gateway Service** that can take the place of a NAT Instance. The benefits of using a NAT Gateway service are:

- It is a fully-managed service -- just create it and it works automatically, including fail-over
- It can burst up to 10 Gbps (a NAT Instance is limited to the bandwidth associated with the EC2 instance type)

However:

- Security Groups **cannot** be associated with a NAT Gateway
- You'll need one in each AZ since they only operate in a single AZ

Comment: Can you add one more point in your note?  NAT instances will work if you have IGW on the public subnet. They also restrict the reverse lookup from the internet to your instance in the subnet.

Comment: Now at 2019, NAT gw can be used just in the VPC, allocating a EIP in the "public" subnet or subnet with "internet gateway" and in the internal subnets, just route to the NAT gw.

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html), I see: `An internet gateway is a horizontally scaled, redundant, and highly available VPC component that allows communication between instances in your VPC and the internet. It therefore imposes no availability risks or bandwidth constraints on your network traffic.`. From the description I get the impression that it is an actual hardware device, but managed by AWS. Please correct me if my understanding is off.

Comment: @AbhishekDivekar Nothing has changed. When working with AWS, concentrate on what you would like to achieve, rather than thinking about underlying hardware.

Comment: Great explanation: Just a small question: When the traffic goes out of a NAT instance or a NAT gateway heading towards the internet, will it still pass through the Internet Gateway or it bypasses the Internet Gateway?

Comment: @Sandeep NAT Instances and NAT Gateways exist within a VPC. Therefore any traffic exiting it and travelling to the Internet will still need to pass through the Internet Gateway. If there is no Internet Gateway, then there will be no access to the Internet.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I wonder, if instance need to talk to internet, why I wouldn't keep it in public subnet (and just use route table to forward traffic to IGW) instead of working around from a private subnet and NAT? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of which we call it 'private'?

Comment: @error2007s answers my question. :)

Comment: This answer was apparently copied to medium almost verbatim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690012/aws-vpc-internet-gateway-vs-nat

Comment: Working example: https://github.com/AppicServices/TerraformAwsSamples

Answer (score 138):

As far as NAT gateway vs. NAT instance, either will work.  A NAT instance can be a little cheaper, but the NAT gateway is fully managed by AWS, so it has the advantage of not needing to maintain an EC2 instance just for NATing.

However, for the instances that need to be available to the Internet, NAT gateway/instances aren't what you are looking for.  A NAT will allow private instances (without a public IP) to access the Internet, but not the other way around.  So, for the EC2 instances that need to be available to the Internet, you need to assign a public IP.  There is a workaround if you really need to keep the EC2 instances private - you can use an elastic load balancer to proxy the requests.

Internet Gateways

The Internet Gateway is how your VPC connects to the internet. You use an Internet Gateway with a route table to tell the VPC how internet traffic gets to the internet.

An Internet Gateway appears in the VPC as just a name. Amazon manages the gateway and there's nothing you really have a say in (other than to use it or not; remember that you might want a completely segmented subnet that cannot access the internet at all).

A public subnet means a subnet that has internet traffic routed through AWS's Internet Gateway. Any instance within a public subnet can have a public IP assigned to it (e.g. an EC2 instance with "associate public ip address" enabled).

A private subnet means the instances are not publicly accessible from the internet. They do NOT have a public IP address. For example, you cannot access them directly via SSH. Instances on private subnets may still access the internet themselves though (i.e. by using a NAT Gateway).

Comment: Best answer in terms of NAT vs Internet gateway.

Comment: Great answer. Just a follow-up question: When an EC2 instance on a public subnet has a Public IP, logically it is self sufficient to either receive inbound requests from the internet or make outbound requests to the internet as its IP is routable and reachable. So what additional job does the Internet Gateway do here?

Comment: @Sandeep EC2 instance does not have any real public IP but behind the scene, it is mapped to a private IP address. An internet gateway serves two purposes: to provide a target in your VPC route tables for internet-routable traffic, and to perform network address translation (NAT) for instances that have been assigned public IPv4 addresseS

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

Internet gateway is used to connect a vpc to the internet and NAT gateway is used to connect the Private subnet to the internet(which means what ever traffic is coming to private subnet instance which will forward to the NAT gateway). you need to forward the traffic in the route table to NAT

Route table
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Thanks for the example - helped me out of a bind!

Comment: There is a diagram on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html that clarifies the purpose of NAT gateway and IGW. Both are needed for private subnets to be able to get internet access

Comment: Here are some core concepts I have gathered about VPC and it's components https://medium.com/@madeehak696/aws-vpc-in-brief-928c8e7f4481