# What are the various ways in which an institution can connect their AWS VPC to the Internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc

What are the various way the institutions can connect their AWS VPC to the Internet?
I searched on AWS documentation about VPC but could not figure out

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, a VPC will have Internet Access provided it has been associated with an Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VPCs` access the internet through an `Internet Gateway` or `NAT Gateway`.

`Internet Gateway` is probably the easiest and most common

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

`NAT Gateways` are to allow outbound access only.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat.html

[AWS VPC - Internet Gateway vs. NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690012/aws-vpc-internet-gateway-vs-nat)

Comment: ...Thanks for your response. This helps!

Comment: A good way to show appreciation for an answer is upvote it, and if it answers your question, accept it to help other users who see this question looking for an answer. ;)